# Proving that V ∩ W is infinite if dim V+dim W> n

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that for all subspaces V and W of $R^n$, if $dimV + dimW > n$, then V∩W is infinite.

I was thinking about using the contrapositive "if V∩W is finite, then dimV+ dimW ≤ n", but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: If $x\in V\cap W$ then $cx\in V\cap W$, since it's a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The only finite subspace $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. This is because, for any fixed non-zero $v \in X$, the map $a \mapsto av$ is an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$, so $X$ contains at least as many elements as $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, we are simply insisting that $V \cap W = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, or in terms of dimension, $\operatorname{dim} V \cap W = 0$. If this is the case, then
$$n \ge \operatorname{dim}(V + W) = \operatorname{dim} V + \operatorname{dim} W - \operatorname{dim} V \cap W = \operatorname{dim} V + \operatorname{dim} W,$$
as required.

Comment: If V∩W={0} and dimV∩W=0, how do we know that dim(V+W) is zero? We only know that V∩W shares 0, how can we know that the dimensions of V and W are both zero?

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}(V+W)$ will not be $0$ in general. I did not mean to imply that. I was just saying that $\operatorname{dim} V + \operatorname{dim} W = \operatorname{dim}(V + W)$, and hence is bounded above by $n$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!